# How to keyframe Ocean Modifier Resolution?

Tags: keyframes, ocean-simulation, resolution

Is it possible to keyframe the resolution of the ocean modifier if so?! How? I'm trying to create a land that will wave like its been hit by an earthquake...

Comment: Do you have any video or any sought of thing to figure out how you want to make it look

Comment: You better try the "Wave" modifier and play with the "offset". As with most fields in blender, to add a keyframe, Right click > Insert keyframe in the field

Answer (score 0):

As @Gorgious mentioned use the wave modifier. This example has the Speed and Height set as keyframes, but just experiment with all the settings as it depends on what exactly you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I use a different method instead. I use displacement and shrinkwrap to shake my buildings...